# How would one replace a vector with a linked list c++

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl, linked-list

I have a code with a template class and a few data members, the code for vector looks like this

```
std::vector<Check> ck(100);
```

how would one go about making this into a linked list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
std::list<Check> lck(ck.begin(), ck.end());
```

[`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is a doubly-linked list.

If you want a singly linked list, you can use [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list):

```
std::forward_list<Check> lck(ck.begin(), ck.end());
```

Comment: @juanchipanza thanks but is that all i need to do? cause i want to add a searching function, to go through the list and find stuff.

Comment: @newb12345 Yes, that is all you need to do. Read up on either of the lists, and also the [standard library algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: @newb12345 Of course, it isn't clear from your question *why* you need a linked list. A vector is usually a good choice of container.